# How do I get python to use a firefox addon to download images from a local file

Tags: python, firefox, xpath

I am trying to get python to open a local html file in firefox and then use a addon called "download all" to download the images to a specific folder. I am not able to scrape them for some weird reason. If I can't do it this way I would want to use xpath to do it since the image links are laid out in tables. Is this possible?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't click on the element since it's not a web page element. However you can create a profile for firefox and include addons in that profile that is launched by the webdriver applications. This will allow you to have access to Firebug or other addons. you can set a profile and extend the profile with the addon api is like so:

```
File file = new File("addonName.xpi");
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.addOn.currentVersion", "1.8.1"); // Avoid startup screen
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not a `Python`